# Remove excess months in Excel line graph

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I graphed the following data:

June 2015 - 1000
September 2015 - 25000
December 2015 - 1500
March 2016 - 7500

When I plot the above as a line graph, the graph includes months that are NOT in my data, such as July 2015, August 2015, October 2015, November 2015, etc... Is there a way I can remove those months?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting in the labels for the dates, Excel automatically converts it to a date, which is why it is adding the extra dates in your graph.  Just add a ' before your dates and Excel will treat the cells as text.  For example put 'June 2015 instead of June 2015 in the cells that you are using to make the table.

Answer (score 2):

Format the horizontal axis, and change Axis Type from Automatic (which will be a date axis if Excel notices you're using dates) to Text Axis. This will turn each date for which you have data into its own category on the axis.